# How does one state that a module implements an interface so that a type in the signature is the same as another type?

Tags: module, ocaml, functor

I am creating monads in OCaml and need to compose them, so I created transformers. I implemented the regular monad in terms of the transformer with the Identity monad:

```
module type MONAD = sig
  type 'a m
  val (>>=) : 'a m -> ('a -> 'b m) -> 'b m
  val return : 'a -> 'a m
end

module Identity : MONAD = struct
  type 'a m = 'a
  let (>>=) m f = f m
  let return x = x
end

module OptionT (M : MONAD) : MONAD with type 'a m := ('a option) M.m = struct
  type 'a m = ('a option) M.m
  let (>>=) m f = M.(>>=) m (fun option ->
    match option with
    | Some x -> f x
    | None -> M.return None)
  let return x = M.return @@ Some x
end

module Option = OptionT(Identity)
```

However, I can't do this:

```
open Option
let _ = (Some 1) >>= (fun x -> Some (x + 1))
```

The errors are:

```
(Some 1)

This expression has type 'a option
    but an expression was expected of type 'b option Identity.m

Some (x + 1)

This expression has type 'a option
    but an expression was expected of type 'b option Identity.m
```

If I try to fix the error with `module Identity : MONAD with type 'a m = 'a` I get an error at `module Option = OptionT(Identity)` that states that

```
The type `m' is required but not provided
```

It seems that now, `'a` has *replaced* `'a m` in the signature.

Doing

```
module Option : MONAD with type 'a m := 'a option = struct
  type 'a m = 'a option
    let (>>=) m f =
      match m with
      | Some x -> f x
      | None -> None
  let return x = Some x
end
```

works just fine.

How do I tell the compiler that a module implements a signature so that a type declared in the signature is the same as another type, while still keeping the signature's original type declaration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It seems that now, 'a has replaced 'a m in the signature.

This the effect of destructive substitution, when you write

```
module Identity : MONAD with type 'a m := 'a
```

you are asking the compiler to substitute all instance of `'a m` by `'a`.
Contrarily, standard `with` constraint adds a type equality to the module type

```
 module Identity : MONAD with type 'a m = 'a
```

Looking at your various examples, it seems that you have confused the two, and are using destructive substitution when you meant to add a type constraint:

```
module OptionT(X:Monad) : MONAD with type 'a m = 'a = …
(* or *) module Option : MONAD with type 'a m = 'a option = …
```

and not

```
module OptionT(X:Monad) : MONAD with type 'a m := 'a = …
(* nor *) module Option : MONAD with type 'a m := 'a option = …
```

Answer (score 0):

> This expression has type 'a option but an expression was expected of type 'b option Identity.m

And indeed, the compiler does not know anything about `Identity` except that its signature is `MONAD`. (`: MONAD`) is not something that merely helps the compiler, it hides all information about `Identity` except that its signature is `MONAD`.

So, you can add a type equality for that

```
module Identity : MONAD with type 'a m = 'a = ...
```

and it works.

Comment: OP says he tried that and got `The type \`m' is required but not provided`.